# Не устанавливается модуль requests для python

Tags: python, requests

Ось – Win7. При попытке установить requests через `pip install requests` в консоли все выходит, однако при дальнейшей попытке подключить через `import requests` idle или visual studio выдает ошибку об отсутствии модуля. Есть варианты решения?

Comment: Возможно, у вас несколько версий python стоит -- в одну установили `requests`, а в другой пытались импортировать. Посмотрите переменные окружения в PATH какие пути ведут в папку с питоном к pip

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю убедиться в том, что установка прошла успешно, для начала: pip list в командной строке и посмотреть что вообще установлено.

Так же можно сохранить файл скрипта в текстовом редакторе и запустить его из командной строки.

Еще нужно зайти в Свойства системы → Дополнительно → Переменные среды и убедится в наличии и корректности питоновской PATH

Answer (score 1):

С idle или visual studio я не работал, но в pycharm иногда натыкаюсь на такое поведения, если для проекта настроена не та версия питона, для которой выполнялась установка пакета.

Убедитесь, что версии совпадают. Скорее всего, в ваших IDE настроена третья версия питона, а pip ставил пакет для второй версии.

Если это так, нужно выполнить такую же установку через pip3.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте
py -m pip install reques

Comment: исправьте, пожалуйста, опечатку, и опишите, чем ваш ответ принципиально отличается от предыдущих. (для этого надо нажать ссылку [edit] ниже текста ответа).